# A more recent book (or equivalent resource) on C programming to be acquainted with the latest standards (or the language grammar)

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, c

I have studied books on C like the classic "The C Programming Language [2e]" by Dennis Ritchie, Brian Kernighan or "C-The Complete Reference [4e]" by Herbert Schildt. But these texts are quite old and do not quite deal with the latest standards [They deal with C89 and C99]

Can anyone suggest a good book on C which is more up-to date... and has descriptions of the standards... [Like in K&R book at the end of the book there is a manual but is not the standard: *"This manual describes the C language specified by the draft submitted to ANSI on 31 October, 1988, for approval as "American National Standard for Information Systems—Programming Language C, X3.159-1989." The manual is an interpretation of the proposed standard, not the Standard itself, although care has been taken to make it a reliable guide to the language."*]

Is there any book (or some other equivalent [online?] resource) which deals with modern standard in detail with possible illustrative code examples.

Answer (score 6):

Ben Klemens' *[21st Century C](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/21st-century-c/9781491904428/)*, now in its second edition, doesn't necessarily *precisely* meet this need, but I'd give it a shot anyway—it's not just a "description of the standard", but also covers how modern C is used *in practice*.

Answer (score 4):

If you are already an advanced C programmer, perhaps you need to look at the actual standard, say, for C17. You can find information about the standards, including links to ISO documents here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C.

The technical documentation for some of the modern compilers might also be a help. The same link mentions some of those.